# Laravel eloquent attach auto generate random ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent many to many relationship and I want to use attach() to easily create role_permissions data but the problem is I'm using an UUID for my ID and it throws an error Field 'id' doesn't have a default value. Any way of hijacking the attach() method? so I can set my UUID?

My migration

```
 Schema::create('role_permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('count')->unique();
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->string('role_id');
        $table->string('permission_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My model

```
class Role extends Model
{
  //
public $incrementing = false;

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_roles', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'role_permissions', 'role_id', 'permission_id');
}
}
```

My attach code

```
 $role->permissions()->attach($permission_ids);
```

I know the problem here is that my id is not an incrementing number it's an unique string. My question is how do I "Inject" that unique string to the attach() method? Thank you guys.

Comment: If you have set up your models and the database correctly this should not be a problem, can you please post the database and the models code?

Comment: Can you post your `code`?

Comment: Well basically there is no model because i'm using a many to many relationship. so the attach would just create a query and execute it.

Comment: Code is now added @Paras

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error

> Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

refers to the fact that your database does not know how to fill the `id` field when it's not specified.

Either you edit the schema adding a nullable:

```
 Schema::create('role_permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('count')->unique();
    $table->string('id')->unique()->nullable(); // Bad idea
    $table->string('role_id');
    $table->string('permission_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

or injecting it via attach:

```
 $role->permissions()->attach($permission_ids, ["id" => null]);
```

More info [on Laravel official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

**Update**

For the future developers who encounter this problem you can also set anything inside the attach array, for example:

```
$role->permissions()->attach($permission_ids, ["id" => Uuid::generate()]);
```

**Update 2**

There's also a more clean way to handle this to be honest. I will try to explain it.

You can handle the *Pivot events* inside the event service provider by simply hooking into the `boot`method:

Here's a snippet

```
/App/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
    public function boot()
    {
    Pivot::creating(function($pivot) {
        if ($pivot->getTable() == 'role_permissions') {
            $pivot->id = Uuid::generate();
        }
    });
    }
```

> *Be aware* I do not know if this is actually possible on your laravel version. Mine (5.4.*) works as intended

Comment: This works, but the value of id will be repeating. and I don't want to set the id to null.

Comment: Got it to work. I did this.

foreach($permission_ids as $permission_id)
     {
      $role->permissions()->attach($permission_id, ["id" => Uuid::generate()]);
     }

Comment: Glad to hear that you understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay managed to fixed it, what I did with the help of @Claudio Ludovico Panneta's tip.

```
foreach($permission_ids as $permission_id)
    {
        $role->permissions()->attach($permission_id, ["id" => Uuid::generate()]);
    }
```